# Include text with images being lazy loaded using Intersectionobserver

Tags: javascript, html, intersection-observer

Im not familiar with the Intersection Observer so how could I include like an H2 tag to be loaded only when the image is?
Here is the code I have

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]');

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      const image = entry.target;
      image.src = image.dataset.src;
      observer.unobserve(image);
    }
  });
});

images.forEach((image) => {
  observer.observe(image);
});
```

and here is the html

```
<div>
<img src = "1.jpg">
<!-- <H2>title 1</h2>-->

<img data-src = "2.jpg">
<!-- <H2>title 2</h2>  lazy loaded here-->

<img data-src = "3.jpg">
<!-- <H2>title 3</h2>  lazy loaded here-->
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any point in lazy loading content? Unless your html file is huge then there probably isn't - otherwise you would need add some sort of data attribute to the image telling it where to get the content from (probably need to ajax load it, otherwise you're just moving your html from your page into your js file)

Answer (score 0):

not sure you really need intersectionObserver here, except if you site is really hug, with a lot of images, there is a simple solution.

just check if image are loaded, if they are put the h2 display block. img have src not data-src, h2 at beginning are display none.

checking is done with an addeventlistener, which is remove when loaded to clean stuff.

if you have a huge site, you can use this inside the intersectionobrserver.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach(elim => {
  elim.addEventListener('load', checkIm);
});

function checkIm(evt) {
  const image = evt.target;
  console.log(image);
  const h = image.nextElementSibling;
  console.log(h);
  h.style.display = 'block';
  image.removeEventListener('load', checkIm);
}
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
}

h2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/600/600">
  <h2>title 1</h2>

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/182/600/600">
  <h2>title 2</h2>

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/121/600/600">
  <h2>title 3</h2>
</div>
```